# I am having difficulty vertically aligning a nav element inside its parent div.

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

Everything I try creates a new problem. It often gets pushed out when I use the `line-height:` property as well. How can I successfully center this element?

CSS:

```
#parent {
    background: #000; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed ;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#child {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px; 
}

ul.menu2 {
    cursor: default;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.menu2 li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0 0 0 0.5em;
    margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
        <nav id="child" role="navigation">
            <ul class="menu2">
                <li><a href="#home" rel="home_link" class="scrolly">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#banner" rel="about_link" class="scrolly scrolly-centered">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#first" rel="events_link" class="scrolly">Shows</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="artists_link">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="contact_link">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `line-height` and `inline-block` to `vertical-align`, you should not use `float`. `text-align` will do.

You can set `height` of `nav` with `line-height` and set `ul` on the middle of it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/PD9Mr/)**

```
#parent {
    background: #000; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    text-align:right;/* ul will go right */
    line-height: 70px;/* as ul should stand on one line, it is enought to size height of nav */
    position: fixed ;
    z-index: 1;/* 1 should do it */
}

#child {
    display: inline-block;/* make me an inline-box, now i can hold anything, block, float, multi-lines, .. */
    text-align: center;/* reset text-align */
    margin-right: 30px; /* or padding-right, whatever */
    vertical-align:middle;/* set me on middle of line-height */
}

ul.menu2 {
    cursor: default;
    border : 0;
    margin : 0;/* usefull reset i believe :) */
    line-height:1.2em; /* reset line-height here to regular values :) in case text , inline-boxes split on 2 or more lines*/
}

ul.menu2 li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0.5em;
    margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. That `float:` always gets me into trouble. However, for some reason `z-index: 1;` does not keep that element in-front of everything else.

Comment: it might be because elsewhere you used as well hudge values for z-index.

Comment: The original CSS on the project is not mine. I see there are other places where huge `z-index:` values are used. I assumed there were reasons the original developer used such large values. What is the correct way to stack elements using `z-index:`? 1 for the top and all below as respective decimal values lower than 1?

Comment: 0 is default value of document , 1 is higher and then 2 and so non. It will work the same if you set 9998 and then 9999 . It does not take decimal values but can take negative values in some browsers. the highhest value will show on top of others, that you start stacking from 1 or 9990, rule is the same :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7E7Qq/1/)**

```
ul.menu2 {
    cursor: default;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0; /* add this to remove default margin from ul */
}
ul.menu2 li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 70px; /* add this equal to the height of the parent to make it vertical center*/
    padding: 0 0 0 0.5em;
    margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use table layout :

```css
#child {
   text-align: center;
   margin-right: 30px; 
   height: 100%;
}

ul.menu2 {
   cursor: default;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
   display: table;
}

ul.menu2 li {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: 1em;
   padding: 0 0 0 0.5em;
   margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WzZM/1/)